# Single ClientID used for multiple users?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am trying to make sure that all users upload to a certain folder for a project.
I have looked at OAuth2 but I need the users to upload using the project's account rather than their own so nothing can get deleted.

Could
data.clientId = config.client_id;
be amended so that only the project account ID was used?  And how would I find the ID for that user?

Comment: There is a possibility that you've misunderstood 'client id'. 'client id' refers to the application, not the user of that application. So assuming all of your users will be using the same app, they will also be using the same client id. Reading between the lines of your question, I think that a Service Account is what you are looking for. https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts

Comment: Thanks for that pinoyyid.  I am pretty much in the dark with this stuff.  I'm basically wanting every user to use the 'Save to Google Drive' extension, but for all the uploads to go to the project account's drive and the extension to be signed in as the project rather than the user.  Users would be able to view, but not edit (or delete) documents once uploaded.

Comment: You won't be able to use that extension, because (as you've spotted) any files saved that way are owned by the user. You'll need your own extension that does the same thing, but uses a Service Account to save to a common drive account.

Comment: Thanks pinoyyid - i had discounted Service accounts because i read that you can't increase the drive size once allocated.  When i tested sharing the project folder with edit rights, a user could delete all the files in that folder, even though they had never touched them before.  That's why i wanted everything locked away.  I'll have another stab at this later - really appreciate your input.

Comment: Provided that you're using server flow (ie. not embedded/Javascript) you can use an ordinary user as the "owner" in place of a Service Account. You will simply need to login as that use one time to authorise access and generate a refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant an access token for your "single" Drive account and use the same access token to authenticate all of the calls.